# If a phone is encrypted (Android 5.1) but user doesn't use a screen lock, and then does factory reset, is data secure?

Tags: factory-reset, 5.1-lollipop, encryption

If I have a phone running Android 5.1 and it is encrypted, but I don't use a lock/PIN for unlocking and using the phone, does that mean if if I do a factory reset, the data on the phone can still be recovered? I mean, does not using a screen lock mess up this process of encryption+factory reset to wipe data?

Comment: If user password/PIN/pattern is not set, data is encrypted with the [`default_password`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-5.1.0_r1/cryptfs.c#79) provided that encryption is enabled. And encrypted data is highly unlikely to be recoverable after factory reset. See my answers to [Data deleted after encryption - recoverable?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214501/218526) and [Can user data be recovered after formatting and flashing stock ROM?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214497/218526).

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thank you. If the data was not encrypted, then there's a good chance it can be recovered even after fctry reset, isn't there?

Comment: Yes............