# Internal memory block device like "/dev/block/mmcblk0" is missing

Tags: twrp, data-recovery

I would like to ask for an advice. I've got LG V40 mobile phone from a friend. Unfortunatelly, he has done factory reset even though he had important photos in the phone (internal memory). I would like to make block a copy via dd and try to rescue at least some photos. Someone already rooted the phone and installed TWRP there and I don't know what else. Now I can only access fastboot and TWRP on the phone. When I list "/dev/block" folder through adb, I can see this:

```
judypn:/ # ls -la /dev/block/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root       2660 2019-09-09 06:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root   root       4620 2019-09-09 06:33 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root         37 2019-09-09 06:33 bootdevice -> /dev/block/platform/soc/1d84000.ufshc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root       1940 2019-09-09 06:33 by-name
brw-------  1 root   root     7,   0 2019-09-09 06:33 loop0
brw-------  1 root   root     7,   8 2019-09-09 06:33 loop1
brw-------  1 root   root     7,  16 2019-09-09 06:33 loop2
brw-------  1 root   root     7,  24 2019-09-09 06:33 loop3
brw-------  1 root   root     7,  32 2019-09-09 06:33 loop4
brw-------  1 root   root     7,  40 2019-09-09 06:33 loop5
brw-------  1 root   root     7,  48 2019-09-09 06:33 loop6
brw-------  1 root   root     7,  56 2019-09-09 06:33 loop7
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root         60 2019-09-09 06:33 platform
brw-------  1 root   root     1,   0 2019-09-09 06:33 ram0
brw-------  1 root   root     1,   1 2019-09-09 06:33 ram1
brw-------  1 root   root     1,  10 2019-09-09 06:33 ram10
brw-------  1 root   root     1,  11 2019-09-09 06:33 ram11
brw-------  1 root   root     1,  12 2019-09-09 06:33 ram12
brw-------  1 root   root     1,  13 2019-09-09 06:33 ram13
brw-------  1 root   root     1,  14 2019-09-09 06:33 ram14
brw-------  1 root   root     1,  15 2019-09-09 06:33 ram15
brw-------  1 root   root     1,   2 2019-09-09 06:33 ram2
brw-------  1 root   root     1,   3 2019-09-09 06:33 ram3
brw-------  1 root   root     1,   4 2019-09-09 06:33 ram4
brw-------  1 root   root     1,   5 2019-09-09 06:33 ram5
brw-------  1 root   root     1,   6 2019-09-09 06:33 ram6
brw-------  1 root   root     1,   7 2019-09-09 06:33 ram7
brw-------  1 root   root     1,   8 2019-09-09 06:33 ram8
brw-------  1 root   root     1,   9 2019-09-09 06:33 ram9
brw-------  1 root   root     8,   0 2019-09-09 06:33 sda
brw-------  1 root   root     8,   1 2019-09-09 06:33 sda1
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  10 2019-09-09 06:33 sda10
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  11 2019-09-09 06:33 sda11
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  12 2019-09-09 06:33 sda12
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  13 2019-09-09 06:33 sda13
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  14 2019-09-09 06:33 sda14
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  15 2019-09-09 06:33 sda15
brw-------  1 root   root   259,   0 2019-09-09 06:33 sda16
brw-------  1 root   root   259,   1 2019-09-09 06:33 sda17
brw-------  1 root   root   259,   2 2019-09-09 06:33 sda18
brw-------  1 root   root   259,   3 2019-09-09 06:33 sda19
brw-------  1 root   root     8,   2 2019-09-09 06:33 sda2
brw-------  1 root   root   259,   4 2019-09-09 06:33 sda20
brw-------  1 root   root   259,   5 2019-09-09 06:33 sda21
brw-------  1 root   root   259,   6 2019-09-09 06:33 sda22
brw-------  1 root   root   259,   7 2019-09-09 06:33 sda23
brw-------  1 root   root   259,   8 2019-09-09 06:33 sda24
brw-------  1 root   root   259,   9 2019-09-09 06:33 sda25
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  10 2019-09-09 06:33 sda26
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  11 2019-09-09 06:33 sda27
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  12 2019-09-09 06:33 sda28
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  13 2019-09-09 06:33 sda29
brw-------  1 root   root     8,   3 2019-09-09 06:33 sda3
brw-------  1 root   root     8,   4 2019-09-09 06:33 sda4
brw-------  1 root   root     8,   5 2019-09-09 06:33 sda5
brw-------  1 root   root     8,   6 2019-09-09 06:34 sda6
brw-------  1 root   root     8,   7 2019-09-09 06:34 sda7
brw-------  1 root   root     8,   8 2019-09-09 06:33 sda8
brw-------  1 root   root     8,   9 2019-09-09 06:33 sda9
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  16 2019-09-09 06:33 sdb
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  17 2019-09-09 06:33 sdb1
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  18 2019-09-09 06:33 sdb2
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  32 2019-09-09 06:33 sdc
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  33 2019-09-09 06:33 sdc1
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  34 2019-09-09 06:33 sdc2
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  48 2019-09-09 06:33 sdd
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  49 2019-09-09 06:33 sdd1
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  50 2019-09-09 06:33 sdd2
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  51 2019-09-09 06:33 sdd3
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  64 2019-09-09 06:33 sde
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  65 2019-09-09 06:33 sde1
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  74 2019-09-09 06:33 sde10
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  75 2019-09-09 06:33 sde11
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  76 2019-09-09 06:33 sde12
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  77 2019-09-09 06:33 sde13
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  78 2019-09-09 06:33 sde14
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  79 2019-09-09 06:33 sde15
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  14 2019-09-09 06:33 sde16
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  15 2019-09-09 06:33 sde17
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  16 2019-09-09 06:33 sde18
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  17 2019-09-09 06:33 sde19
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  66 2019-09-09 06:33 sde2
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  18 2019-09-09 06:33 sde20
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  19 2019-09-09 06:33 sde21
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  20 2019-09-09 06:33 sde22
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  21 2019-09-09 06:33 sde23
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  22 2019-09-09 06:33 sde24
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  23 2019-09-09 06:33 sde25
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  24 2019-09-09 06:33 sde26
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  25 2019-09-09 06:33 sde27
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  26 2019-09-09 06:33 sde28
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  27 2019-09-09 06:33 sde29
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  67 2019-09-09 06:33 sde3
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  28 2019-09-09 06:33 sde30
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  29 2019-09-09 06:33 sde31
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  30 2019-09-09 06:33 sde32
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  31 2019-09-09 06:33 sde33
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  32 2019-09-09 06:33 sde34
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  33 2019-09-09 06:33 sde35
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  34 2019-09-09 06:33 sde36
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  35 2019-09-09 06:33 sde37
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  36 2019-09-09 06:33 sde38
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  37 2019-09-09 06:33 sde39
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  68 2019-09-09 06:33 sde4
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  38 2019-09-09 06:33 sde40
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  39 2019-09-09 06:33 sde41
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  40 2019-09-09 06:33 sde42
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  41 2019-09-09 06:33 sde43
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  42 2019-09-09 06:33 sde44
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  43 2019-09-09 06:33 sde45
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  44 2019-09-09 06:33 sde46
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  45 2019-09-09 06:33 sde47
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  46 2019-09-09 06:33 sde48
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  47 2019-09-09 06:33 sde49
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  69 2019-09-09 06:33 sde5
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  48 2019-09-09 06:33 sde50
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  49 2019-09-09 06:33 sde51
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  50 2019-09-09 06:33 sde52
brw-------  1 root   root   259,  51 2019-09-09 06:33 sde53
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  70 2019-09-09 06:33 sde6
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  71 2019-09-09 06:33 sde7
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  72 2019-09-09 06:33 sde8
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  73 2019-09-09 06:33 sde9
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  80 2019-09-09 06:33 sdf
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  81 2019-09-09 06:33 sdf1
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  82 2019-09-09 06:33 sdf2
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  83 2019-09-09 06:33 sdf3
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  84 2019-09-09 06:33 sdf4
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  85 2019-09-09 06:33 sdf5
brw-------  1 root   root     8,  96 2019-09-09 06:33 sdg
brw-------  1 system system   8,  97 2019-09-09 06:33 sdg1
brw-------  1 root   root   254,   0 2019-09-09 06:33 zram0
brw-------  1 root   root   254,   1 2019-09-09 06:33 zram1
```

There is no device like "/dev/block/mmcblk0". This should represent whole device internal memory. Am I right? What could be a problem? Or how can I address and copy (block level) whole internal memory? My knowledge about Android is really limited so I appreciate every hint you can give me. Thank you!

Comment: If you are talking about the "LG V40 ThinQ" released in 2018 this phone came with Android 8.1 according to PhoneArena. As far as I know this means it is encrypted by default. A factory reset deleted the encryption key so any data recovery you try will fail. You can check the device. If in settings -> security -> encryption is enabled after the factory reset then you can stop.

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209999/data-deleted-after-encryption-recoverable

Comment: Your device must have an UFS storage chip, not eMMC. `sd[a|b|c|...]` and `mmcblk[0|1|2|...]` are just naming conventions in Linux kernel for different types of storage devices. Read this: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-pk/000132092/ubuntu-linux-terms-for-your-hard-drive-and-devices-explained

Comment: *adb pull /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata*

Comment: Thank you guys. I can't check whether is encryption enabled by default, because I can't even boot Android. Someone messed that up during twrp installation.  But I can't mount user data partition in twrp (clicking the check box does nothing) so I suppose that it's unfortunatelly encrypted. I pulled data out using "adb pull /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata" a I ran "scalpel" on that file to be sure but without success.